# Django display values of a choice

Tags: django

If I take for example the manual of Django :

```
from django import forms

FAVORITE_COLORS_CHOICES = (
    ('blue', 'Blue'),
    ('green', 'Green'),
    ('black', 'Black'),
)

class SimpleForm(forms.Form):
    favorite_colors = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        required=False,
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        choices=FAVORITE_COLORS_CHOICES,
    )
```

In my template, I just want to display the value of the checkbox.
Something like this :

```
{% for item in favorite_colors %}
  {{value_of_checkbox}} {{item}}
{% endfor %}
```

I want `{{value_of_checkbox}}` return "blue", "green" and "black"

And so the `{{item}}` return "Blue", "Green" and "Black"

Any way to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{% for item in favorite_colors %}
  {{get_item_display}} {{item}}
{% endfor %}
```

try this hope it helps

Comment: Thank you, I try something else, your post was helpfull

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to manually render it. Just use it like this in your template:

```
{{ favorite_colors }}
```

If you need additional css classes on this section, add them at the form widget, inside your `forms.py`, like this:

```
...
widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(atts={'css_class': 'a_value'})
...
```

Comment: then you can use custom filters, which you will need to call on each instance within your forloop.

Comment: @GrandGTO mind marking my answer as a solution to your question by clicking on the green mark if you think it helped you :) Thanks!